# What is the barebones C++ code necessary to put a jpeg into MySQL table?

Tags: c++, mysql, image, blob, jpeg

I have created a MySQL table where one of the columns stores a BLOB type. (The Internet told me BLOB is the correct data type for images.)

I am pretty much a beginner with both C++ and MySQL. What I would like to do is to write a small program with a main() that puts a jpeg into that table. For the sake of this exercise, I do not want to store a reference to a directory that contains an image.

Am I wrong to think that it is as simple as filling out the part in BLOCK 2 below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    //BLOCK 1: INIT
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    int query_state;

    mysql_init(&mysql);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "secret", "beginner_db",0,0,0);

    //BLOCK 2: SEND QUERY
    /* do something to insert image to table */

    //BLOCK 3: DISPLAY QUERY RESULTS
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    /* do something with result */

    //BLOCK 4: FREE
    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(connection);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just want to point out that it's generally good not to store files in database. There might be an exception I never found one.

Comment: @TomášZato I have since learned first hand that databases with images are difficult to backup and restore, since they grow in size very quickly. Also, I encountered a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62037) which crashes mysqld when a BLOB is updated and being read at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, a good solution would be to use the [`mysql_stmt_send_long_data()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-send-long-data.html) function.

There is an example on the MySQL Manual page that I linked to, but here is a more relevant example of sending file contents:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>

#include <mysql.h>

#define ARR_LEN(arr_id) ((sizeof (arr_id))/(sizeof (arr_id)[0]))

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    MYSQL *pconn = mysql_init(NULL);
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT( (pconn) ) {
        mysql_close(pconn);
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    const char *db_name = "test";
    if (!mysql_real_connect(pconn, "localhost", "test", "********", db_name, 0, NULL, CLIENT_COMPRESS)) {
        cerr << "Error: mysql_real_connect() failed to connect to `" << db_name << "`." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    MYSQL_STMT *pinsert_into_images_stmt = mysql_stmt_init(pconn);
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT( (pinsert_into_images_stmt) ) {
        mysql_stmt_close(pinsert_into_images_stmt);
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    const char sql1[] = "INSERT INTO images(data) VALUES (?)";
    if (mysql_stmt_prepare(pinsert_into_images_stmt, sql1, strlen(sql1)) != 0) {
        cerr << "Error: mysql_stmt_prepare() failed to prepare `" << sql1 << "`." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    MYSQL_BIND bind_structs[] = {
        { 0 } // One for each ?-placeholder
    };

    unsigned long length0;
    bind_structs[0].length = &length0;
    bind_structs[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB;
    bind_structs[0].is_null_value = 0;

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(pinsert_into_images_stmt, bind_structs) != 0) {
        cerr << "Error: mysql_stmt_bind_param() failed." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const char *file_name = "image.jpg";
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT( (fp) ) {
        fclose(fp);
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    // Use mysql_stmt_send_long_data() to send the file data in chunks.
    char buf[10*1024];
    while (!ferror(fp) && !feof(fp)) {
        size_t res = fread(buf, 1, ARR_LEN(buf), fp);
        if (mysql_stmt_send_long_data(pinsert_into_images_stmt, 0, buf, res) != 0) {
            cerr << "Error: mysql_stmt_send_long_data() failed." << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (!feof(fp)) {
        cerr << "Error: Failed to read `" << file_name << "` in its entirety." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (mysql_stmt_execute(pinsert_into_images_stmt) != 0) {
        cerr << "Error: mysql_stmt_execute() failed." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cout << "Inserted record #" << mysql_insert_id(pconn) << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using the following definition of table `` `images` ``:

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Upon running this program, it successfully sent the 38,339-byte JPEG `image.jpg` to the server and outputted "Inserted record #1".

You can verify that the correct number of bytes were sent:

```
mysql> SELECT octet_length(data) FROM images WHERE id=1;
+--------------------+
| octet_length(data) |
+--------------------+
|              38339 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I successfully compiled it but had to remove windows.h and all code referring to BOOST. (I'm running Fedora) It works! Thank you. Now, to sit down and pick apart the individual commands.

Comment: @Morpork: Oh, okay. `windows.h` is Windows-only. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), however, is a cross-platform library. It's important here because I use [Boost Scope Exit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) to [clean up automatically](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/RAII), thus preventing memory and resource leaks. On Fedora, you should be able to install Boost with `yum install boost boost-devel`. If that doesn't work, see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6831

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution that worked... for images under 10kb.

```
//http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/
//g++ -o output source.cpp $(mysql_config --cflags) $(mysql_config --libs)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MYSQL *conn;

  int len, size;
  char data[1000*1024];
  char chunk[2*1000*1024+1];
  char query[1024*5000];

  FILE *fp;

  conn = mysql_init(NULL);
  mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "secret", "beginner_db", 0, NULL, 0);

  fp = fopen("filename.png", "rb");
  size = fread(data, 1, 1024*1000, fp);

  mysql_real_escape_string(conn, chunk, data, size);

  char *stat = "INSERT INTO pic_tbl(name, pic) VALUES('cexample', '%s')";
  len = snprintf(query, sizeof(stat)+sizeof(chunk) , stat, chunk);

  mysql_real_query(conn, query, len);

  fclose(fp);
  mysql_close(conn);
}
```

Comment: I am not too happy with this because of the fixed size allocation and being C. Hopefully someone else can point a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
CString SaveFile( CMemoryFile& File )
{
    *pFileKey = -1;

        SQLRETURN       retcode;
        SQLHSTMT        hstmt;
        CLoggEntryList  LoggEntryList( this ); // logg entries cannot be made while busy inside the hstmt, use this class to add them later
        SQLINTEGER      cbDocumentBlock;        // For binding the main image

        long            lDocumentBufferSize = 0;
        unsigned char*  pDocumentBuffer;        // Will be set to point to the buffer that should be written into the document blob field
        unsigned char   pDummyChar[] = {'0'};   // Dummy buffer to write in the image/thumbnail blob fields when using external storage

                lDocumentBufferSize = File.m_lBufferSize;
                pDocumentBuffer = File.m_pFileBuffer;


        // Allocate statement handle
        retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, m_Database.m_hdbc, &hstmt); 

        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
        {   // Create a result set

            CString szSQL;

            szSQL = ( "INSERT INTO ObjectTable (ObjectData) VALUES (  ? )");

            retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)szSQL.GetBuffer(), SQL_NTS);

            if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
            {
                // Bind the parameters. For parameter 1, pass the parameter number in ParameterValuePtr instead of a buffer address.

                SQLINTEGER cbNULL = 0;
                SQLINTEGER cbTEXT = SQL_NTS;
                int nColumn = 1;

                // Bind ObjectData
                cbDocumentBlock = SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(0); //SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(lImageBufferSize);                    
                retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, nColumn++, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_LONGVARBINARY,
                    0, 0, (SQLPOINTER) DOCUMENT, 0, &cbDocumentBlock);

                if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
                {
                    // Set values so data for parameter 1 will be passed at execution. Note that the length parameter in
                    // the macro SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC is 0. This assumes that the driver returns "N" for the 
                    // SQL_NEED_LONG_DATA_LEN information type in SQLGetInfo.

                    retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt);
                    const long      nMaxChunkSize = 400000;
                    // For data-at-execution parameters, call SQLParamData to get the parameter number set by SQLBindParameter.
                    // Call InitUserData. Call GetUserData and SQLPutData repeatedly to get and put all data for the parameter.
                    // Call SQLParamData to finish processing this parameter.

                    while (retcode == SQL_NEED_DATA) 
                    {
                        SQLPOINTER      pToken;
                        retcode = SQLParamData(hstmt, &pToken);

                        switch( (int)pToken )
                        {
                        case DOCUMENT:
                            {
                                if (retcode == SQL_NEED_DATA)
                                {
                                    for( int nPos = 0; nPos < lDocumentBufferSize; nPos += nMaxChunkSize )
                                    {
                                        int nBufferSize = min( lDocumentBufferSize - nPos, nMaxChunkSize );
                                        SQLRETURN retcode2  = SQLPutData(hstmt, pDocumentBuffer+nPos, nBufferSize );
                                        if (retcode2 != SQL_SUCCESS && retcode2 != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
                                        {
                                            SQLCHAR         Sqlstate[6];
                                            SQLINTEGER      NativeError;
                                            SQLCHAR         MessageText[201];
                                            SQLSMALLINT      TextLengthPtr;

                                            retcode2 = SQLGetDiagRec( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt, 1, Sqlstate, &NativeError, MessageText, 200, &TextLengthPtr );
                                            if (retcode2 == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode2 == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
                                            {
                                                MessageText[TextLengthPtr] = 0;
                                                Sqlstate[5] = 0;

                                                CString szSQLState( Sqlstate );
                                                CString szMessageText( MessageText );

                                                CString szMessage;
                                                szMessage.Format("Error in SaveFile(). SQL State %s. Native %ld. Source: %s", szSQLState, NativeError, szMessageText );
                                                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
                                                return szMessage;
                                            }                                   
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        default:
                            {
                                CString szMessage;
                                szMessage.Format("Error in SaveBuffer(). Unknown parameter buffer.");
                                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
                                return szMessage;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                SQLRETURN retcode3;
                retcode3 = SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
                ASSERT(retcode3 == SQL_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
}
```

**This code is not tested or even compiled**, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This answer is a bit complicated. I appreciate the time you spent answering it though. I found something that seems more transparent to me and I am in a bit of a time constraint so forgive me for neglecting this one.

Comment: no problems. I struggled with this because the low-level SQL-api is quite complicatet.